# Regular Expression for a JSON-type String

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am having trouble splitting a String using a regular expression

```
"[{'name':'abc','surname':'def'},{'name':'ghi','surname':'jkl'},{'name':'asdf','surname':'asdf'}]"
```

Now I'd like to split this to

```
"{'name':'abc','surname':'def'}" and "{'name':'ghi','surname':'jkl'}"
```

Later on I will deserialize both Strings and work with the values. I must admit that I've worked way too little with regular expressions and would love if someone could help me. I want to split by those square brackets as well as by the middle comma. I was either splitting by ALL commas or not splitting at all.

Kind regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Regex will do that:

```
({.*?})
```

and here is a [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/nG0eL9) to prove it.

To use it you might do something like this:

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
// match.Groups has all of the matches
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Regex 101 seems to be useful

Comment: @voskart, yeah Regex 101 is awesome for building Regex patterns. There are a lot of other tools out there, I just prefer that one.